# checking checkbox doesn't check it- JSP

Tags: jsp

Here is my JSP code:

```
<div class="right">
   <label class="styled-checkbox">
      <input id="${ErrorId}" type="checkbox" 
      <c:if test="${not empty resolvedBy}">
         <c:out value='checked' escapeXml="false"/>
      </c:if>
      class="js-issues-mark-resolved">
      <span> Mark as resolved </span>
   </label>
</div>
```

When I check the box check doesn't appear, can someone help me figuring it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follow:

```
<div class="right">
   <label class="styled-checkbox">
      <input id="${ErrorId}" type="checkbox" <c:if test="${not empty resolvedBy}">checked</c:if> class="js-issues-mark-resolved"/>
      <span> Mark as resolved </span>
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: I modify again, try it. I think you need to check `resolvedBy` value.

Comment: Ok, one thing you need to know is that `c:out` is for write on jsp page for show not as an code. You are welcome.